# Array execute in php if empty pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
foreach($parentinfojson as $value) {
    if (!empty($parentinfojson )) {
        $stmt2 = $dbh -> prepare("INSERT INTO parentinfo (last_name,first_name,status) VALUES (:lastname,:firstname,:status)");
        $stmt2_ = $stmt2 -> execute(array(':firstname' => $value['firstname'], ':lastname' => $value['lastname'], ':status' => $status));
    } else {
        $stmt2_ = $stmt2 -> execute();
    }

}

if ($stmt2_ && $stmt3_ && $stmt1_ && $stmt_ && $stmt5_ && $stmt4_) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => false,
        'message' => "Added"
    ));
}
```

This is my execute in `Inserting` new data in the table. When i tested the adding of empty data(`parentinfojson` is empty) i get error that `Notice: Undefined variable: stmt2_`. What i did is i added an `else` statement and i initialize the variable still i get error. I tried to echo something in the else statement as well but i get error. Now I run out of idea on how to initialize the variable when the `json` is empty so that i dont get the error `undefined variable`

Comment: I don't understand why you set your execute in a var

Comment: i have many exec so i need to have them like that so i can check if they all run that is the time i show it is added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just defined `$stmt2` inside the loop, if `$parentinfojson` is empty it'll certainly get undefined. Why not define/initialize it.

```
// initialize up top
$stmt_ = $stmt1_ = $stmt2_ = $stmt3_ = $stmt4_ = $stmt5_ = false;

$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO parentinfo (last_name,first_name,status) VALUES (:lastname,:firstname,:status)");
foreach($parentinfojson as $value) {
    $stmt2_ = $stmt2->execute(array(
        ':firstname' => $value['firstname'], 
        ':lastname' => $value['lastname'], 
        ':status' => $status
    ));
}

if ($stmt2_ && $stmt3_ && $stmt1_ && $stmt_ && $stmt5_ && $stmt4_) {
    echo json_encode(array(
        'error' => false,
        'message' => "Added"
    ));
}
```

Sidenote: Another way would be to build the query dynamically, including the placeholders and the values. So that in turn, you don't have to loop each batches of insert but instead, creating the SQL batch insert then binding all of the values into one single insert invocation:

```
$stmt_ = $stmt1_ = $stmt2_ = $stmt3_ = $stmt4_ = $stmt5_ = false;

if(!empty($parentinfojson)) {
    $base_query = 'INSERT INTO parentinfo (last_name, first_name, status) VALUES ';
    $placeholders = implode(',', array_map(function($batch){
        return '(' . implode(',', array_fill(0, count($batch), '?')) . ')';
    }, $parentinfojson));
    $base_query .= $placeholders;
    $parentinfojson = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map('array_values', $parentinfojson));
    $stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($base_query);
    $stmt2_-> $stmt2->execute($parentinfojson);
}
```

Comment: `$stmt2;` this is actually what i tried. I put it before the `foreach` when i used your code and put it together with all initialization it worked. i dont understand what is the difference of your way and mine lol but it worked anyway

Comment: your updated answer that is exactly what i did.it worked. what is the difference of what you did and what i did can you explain a bit

Comment: @HogRider just intialized the variable, you see when `$parentinfojson` if empty, your variables inside will never be defined thus the undefined variable. and i just took off that prepare outside, you don't need to loop the `->prepare` you only need it once, from there, loop the `->execute`

Comment: i need put all other prepare outside of the for loop.lol thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

There might be a chance that the json variable you are receiving is not empty, so you should also add a check for valid json, this is the function to check a valid json

```
function isJson($string) {
   json_decode($string);
   return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

Comment: i added `print_r();` before and it returned `Array ( ) ` so it is an empty array.

Comment: So then if it is an array, then add check as count ($parentinfojson) > 0)